# How to structure python modules/packages according to dependecy inversion

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-inversion, circular-dependency

If I am working on a project, say it has this file structure:

```
car/
   body/
      __init__.py
      doors.py
      bonnet.py
   engine/
      cyclinderhead/
          __init__.py
          pistons.py
      __init__.py
      crankshaft.py
      engconstants.py
    utilities.py
```

Now invariabley the `pistons.py` file will need some sort of constant (`engconstants.py`) or utility function (`utilities.py`). The `pistons.py` is a very nested deep file. Is it okay that it depends on files higher up in the file structure? I got the impression that the less nested files should only depend on the more nested files, and depencies going the other way are a code smell? I often get myself into circular import predicaments and am trying to implement a set of rules/guidelines to prevent that.

Comment: Are we to assume that each python file has only one class? For example pistons.py has class Pistons() and so on, or can you give an examples of how the classes are structured?